# Postgresql throws null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint for GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, h2

I'm trying to autogenerate id's for my entity:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

My DB table is created via flyway script, and column ID is set as IDENTITY

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
   ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
};
```

Then I'm trying to save this entity with my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

like this:

```
userRepository.save(user);
```

however this results in an error

> null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

This only shows while connected to PostgreSQL:12.2, if I run the same code with h2 database it works fine.

Why is this failing in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Works for me with Hibernate 5.4

Answer (score 0):

you should create sequence and use that sequence for id

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq", sequenceName = "user_id_seq")
    private long id;
```

and you should create sequence in postgresql:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq
INCREMENT 5
START 10;
```

Comment: An `identity` column already has a sequence and Hibernate should be smart enough to honor the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` annotation - this smells like a Hibernate bug. Using a proper `identity` column is the correct (Postgres) way to do it.

Comment: i think hibernate seach in database for correct sequence, and when it cannot find proper one, it may failed but i  agree with you that hibernate isn't smart enough

Comment: Hibernate should simply not send a value at all, e.g. generating `insert into users (name) values ('bla')` - and this is what Hibernate (5.4) does in my code

Comment: which version of hibernate you use?

Comment: i find this in postgres mailing list https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200910101056.24051.robert@paulsenonline.net

Answer (score -1):

make users table

CREATE TABLE USERS (
ID serial NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
};

Comment: How is this different to the CREATE TABLE statement in the question?